# Oracle: Update using IN (Association Array)

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have generated a list of associated array(aArray) which contain all the primary key.

May I know how I can use it to update those primary keys?

Example:

```
Update animal an set status='dead' where an.pk in (aArray)
```

May I know is there a way beside the following methods:

1) looping the array and updating each record individually?(performance)

2) looping the array and draft the element string. (23123,3123,3123,3123,123)

?????

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/associative-arrays-9i.php), it might be of some help. This [one](http://psoug.org/reference/arrays.html) is quite similar.

Comment: yup saw those but that is not what I need.

Comment: can you make your array in schema level ? I mean as DB type and not a plsql type

Comment: I don't understand, care to explain? what is DB Type and PLSQL TYPE?

Comment: @seesee, can your array get created as an object in the schema, i.e. `create or replace type ANIMAL_ARRAY as TABLE OF NUMBER;` ? and not inside a plsql block i.e. `DECLARE type animal_array is table of number; aArray animal_array; BEGIN ...`

Comment: oh mine is inside PLSQL, what is the difference and how does it provide the solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can have your array as type in the schema level then you can try something like this:

```
create or replace type ANIMAL_ARRAY as TABLE OF NUMBER;
/

DECLARE
  aArray ANIMAL_ARRAY := new ANIMAL_ARRAY(1,2,3);
BEGIN
  Update animal an set status='dead' 
   where an.pk in (select column_value from table(aArray));
END;
```

If the array is a schema level type then you can use the `table` keyword to refer to it as a regular table.

Comment: If I do not wish to CREATE TYPE.. is there any other solution?